# How can I remove this new window in IntelliJ run sidebar?

Tags: intellij-idea

I updated my IntelliJ Idea yesterday, and I now see this window that shows my error tree on the run toolbar and I can't remove it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az7FB.png

Comment: Add some screenshots , they will be vital in assisting you

Answer (score 0):

Click the minus sign (-) at the right top that panel

Comment: No, that just collapses the whole toolbar, I need just the left part.